# How to create a new file everytime the output buffer is flushed?

Tags: java

The below code generates all possible combinations of 14 elements in a given array with 26 elements (total of 9,657,700 combinations).

I need to flush the buffer everytime it reaches 1,048,575 lines, creating a new file.

Although it creates a few files, only the first one is filled with the combinations generated (all 9,657,700 combinations).

What should be done so that all files are filled with 1,048,575 combinations each?

Thanks.

```
package numbercombination2;
import java.io.*;

class NumberCombination2 {

    static void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start,
                        int end, int index, int r, long[] g, BufferedWriter bw, int[] count) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        if (index == r) {
            
            for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
                bw.write(data[j]+";");
                bw.newLine();
                count[0]++;

            //*=====> Is it possible to create a new file everytime the output buffer is flushed?
            if (count[0] % 1048575 == 0) {
                bw.flush();
                g[0]++;
                System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Combinations - " + g[0] + ".txt")));
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
            }

            return;
        }

        for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++) {
            data[index] = arr[i];
            combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r, g, bw, count);
        }
    }

    static void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r, long[] g, BufferedWriter bw, int[] count) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    
        int data[]=new int[r];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r, g, bw, count);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26};
        int r = 14;
        int n = arr.length;

        long[] g = new long[1];
        g[0]++;
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Combinations - " + g[0] + ".txt")));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        int[] count = new int[]{0}; //for counting total amount of all combination numbers

        printCombination(arr, n, r, g, bw, count);
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its very similar to the OP previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69420504/is-there-a-faster-way-to-split-results-into-multiple-files

Comment: There is no need to redirect System.out with `setOut`. Use `bw` directly to the FileOutputStream and call `bw.close()` not flush - this should ensure last file you opened was completed before opening the next one.

Comment: Are these the changes to be done?        `if (count[0] % 1048575 == 0)
                        {
                                bw.close();
                                g[0]++;
                                bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("Combinations - " + g[0] + ".txt"))));
                        }`.        Unfortunately, there is an error message regarding `bw`: "assigned value is never used". How could this problem be solved?

Comment: Edit your question with proper formatted code, I will post answer to help you on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related to fact that `bw` changes inside the recursive calls to `combinationUtil`, but the caller does not see the new `bw` - so once out of one invocation, the caller has reference to the old `bw` file and this is probably why everything ended up in the first file you opened.

One way to fix would be to return `bw` from `combinationUtil()` so the latest value of the buffered writer is always used at every level, and every call must re-assign back to the methods local variable:

```
bw = combinationUtil( ... , bw, ...)
```

However your code is a over complex: several of the parameters for combinationUtil are just global variables. I suggest you refactor so that you kick off the run with:

```
 NumberCombination2 combos = new NumberCombination2();
 combos.printCombination(arr, n, r);
```

... and add bw / g/ count as `NumberCombination2` instance variables, reduce arguments to methods `combinationUtil` / `printCombination` and make them non-static:

```
BufferedWriter bw;
long g;
int count;
```

Finally, always set up well defined file handling in one place (not in main and combinationUtil). Say add newFile / close which you call in one place BEFORE the first line bw.write:

```
combinationUtil( ... ) {
    if ((++count % 1048575 == 0) || bw == null)
        newFile();
    for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
        bw.write(data[j] + ";");
    ...
}

void close() throws IOException {
    if (bw != null)
        bw.close();
}
void newFile() throws IOException {
    close();
    Path file = Path.of("Combinations - " + (++g) + ".txt");
    System.out.println("Writing to: "+file);
    bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(file);
}
```

Remember to add `close();` to printCombination so that all file handling is complete.

Comment: DuncG, I have a limited knowledge of java. I did my best trying to implement all your corrections, but there is a problem regarding to the `Path`. Please check the updated code. Am I missing something in the code?

Comment: If you have older JDK then replace my `Path.of` by `Paths.get` and `import java.nio.file.*`

Comment: DuncG, Is it possible to set a second path in `Path.of` so that when the first disk is full, then the files are saved in the second disk?

Comment: Put the files wherever you want to as `Path.of()` accepts any OS pathname either as one parameter or separated as the individual components. eg `Path.of("mydir", "subdir", "xyz.txt")` or `Path.of("mydir/subdir/xyz.txt")` or `Path.of("c:\\mydir\\subdir\\xyz.txt")` or `Path.of("c:/mydir", "subdir\\xyz.txt")`

Comment: I asked if it is possible to specify 2 different paths, in 2 different disks. The code starts saving the files in disk 1 and when disk 1 is full, begins to save the files in disk 2.

Comment: Path is single, you can switch Path to another disk when you determine the disk is full.